# Using a User Defined Datatype as a Stored Procedure parameter?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following that I declared in my database:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[QuestionList] AS TABLE (
    [QuestionUId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL);
```

I am using the datatype like this in the same database:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_ins
       @Title          NVARCHAR (100) ,
       @Questions      QuestionList READONLY,
       @TopicId        INT                           
AS 
BEGIN
```

In my C# calling program I have:

```
    DataTable questions = new DataTable("QUIDs");
    questions.Columns.Add("testId", typeof(Guid));
    foreach (Guid id in tqh) {
        questions.Rows.Add(id);
    }
```

I call the stored procedure with:

```
parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter ("@Questions", questions));
```

The problem is I get the following message:

```
exceptionMessage=The table type parameter '@Questions' must have a valid type name.
```

Can anyone give me an idea what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Side note: [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187926.aspx): "Avoid the use of the **sp_** prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures. Using the prefix can cause application code to break if there is a system procedure with the same name."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that I was missing specifying a TypeName on the SqlParameter. I corrected it like this:

```
var p = new SqlParameter ("@Questions", questions);
p.TypeName = "dbo.QuestionList";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute your stored procedure from SSMS by following query without any problem.

```
DECLARE @Questions QuestionList 
INSERT INTO @Questions( QuestionUId )VALUES (NEWID())
EXEC dbo.sp_ins N'', @Questions, 0
```

Also you can execute your stored procedure from C# code by following code (Sample):

Convet data to DataTable:

```
public class Record
{
    public Guid QuestionUId { get; set; }
}
private DataTable CreateDataTable(IEnumerable<Record> records)
{
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("QuestionUId", typeof(Guid));
foreach (Record record in records)
{
table.Rows.Add(record.QuestionUId);
}
return table;
}
```

Table Valued SP caller

```
public static IEnumerable<Record> TableValuedSPCaller(DataTable inputTable)
{
using (var context = new MyContext(MyConnectionString))
      {
var tableParam = new SqlParameter 
{ 
ParameterName="@Questions",
Value = inputTable, 
TypeName = "dbo.QuestionList"
};
return context.Database.SqlQuery<Record/*ResultType*/>
("dbo.sp_ins @Questions", tableParam);
        }
}
```

Call table valued SP:

```
var records = new List<Record>
{
new Record{QuestionUId=Guid1},
new Record{QuestionUId=Guid1},
new Record{QuestionUId=Guid1}
};
DataTable tableParameter = CreateDataTable(records);
var result = TableValuedSPCaller (tableParameter);
```

Comment: You gave a good long example but I think it's not exactly an answer to my question. Can you see anything wrong with the way I have coded as I detailed in my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

can you please try the following once in your Stored Procedure,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_ins
       @Title          NVARCHAR (100) ,
       --@Questions  QuestionList READONLY,   
       @Questions  AS    QuestionList READONLY,      <-------CHANGED
       @TopicId        INT                           
AS 
BEGIN
```